# Why getCount () larger than adapter dataset repeats positions

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a very simple adapter here. One where i want a lot of blank spaces in the list. Let's say 1,000. The dataset behind the adapter has only 5 elements in it. When this adapter gets loaded into a listview everything looks ok until you scroll off screen. Then positions repeat and data from the dataset gets loaded. Why? Does getCount(), when overridden, need to always return a size that is actually in the dataset?

```
private abstract class BlankEntriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<String> rowList;

    public BlankEntriesAdapter(List<String> rowList) {
        this.rowList = rowList;         
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //force a few blank spaces
        return 1000;                    
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        if (position < rowList.size()) {
            return rowList.get(position);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        RowItem item = getItem(position);

        if (item != null) {
            return item.rowId;
        }

        return 0L;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return position < rowList.size();


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //ISSUE IS HERE. Position numbers start to repeat. Expect position to match what row was drawn to screen. 
    String stringItem = getItem(position);

    /*Load string to view if not null. Code not shown.*/
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing inside `getView()`? That is important!

I imagine the problem is that inside `getView()` you are returning `convertView` unmodified, which is already initialised to represent an earlier row in the list. Basically the list view will keep recycling `View`s as they scroll off the top off the list (for efficiency) and passing them back to to the adapter to reuse.

If `convertView` is not null then you need to manually reset any views or properties you might have set on it in earlier calls to `getView()`, or inflate and return a new `View` object. Otherwise you will observe the repeating rows problem you describe.

Comment: The problem was really two fold One was in getItemId() and the second was in getView(). Your suggestion got me going in the right direction. The convertView was never being reset when positions got larger than the internal List<>. Brain fart on my end, I manipulate these things all the time believe it or not lol.